# how to return a unticked value from a checkbox in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

my value is returned as yes if checkbox is ticked but it does not return a value if unticked

here is my html

```
<input id="contactMe" type="checkbox" name="MarketingOptIn" checked value="no">
```

here is the javascript/jquery

```
<script>
$("#contactMe").click(function(){
if ($("#contactMe").is(':checked')){
    $(this).val("yes");
} else {
    $(this).val("no");
}
});
</script>
```

if ticked and submitted i get the value "yes" but if unticked then submitted i get [$MarketingOptIn]

Comment: It actually works: [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ajatORA/1/edit?html,js,output). Also, I think that the initial value should be "yes" since its checked.

Comment: @Beterraba yeah, the value will change, but the form will still not submit the value to the server.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a form with a checkbox that is unchecked the value will **not** appear in the input set - this is intentional. The same happens if you have radio buttons of which none is selected.

So either you get `MarketingOptIn=yes` or you don't get `MarketingOptIn` at all.

A nice solution is make sure the receiving script knows that it should expect `MarketingOptIn`, and if it's not there assume `MarketingOptIn=no`.

It's common to see something like:

```
$MarketingOptIn = isset($_GET["MarketingOptIn"]) ? "yes" : "no";
```

---

Proper solutions, such as a model driven approach, pretty much take care of these issues but are significantly more involved.

Comment: +1 Here's an (unneeded, but fwiw) proof/resource: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html